# Matching numbers to characters separated by a space in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so:

```
| X | Y 
----------
| 8  | 8 13
| 1  | 8 13  
| 5  | 8 13 
| 13 | 8 13
| 3  | 8 13
| 14 | 7
| 14 |
```

Col X is in integer format. Col Y is in character format, the numbers are separated by a space. This column can have one number (single or double digit), up to 20 numbers, all separated by a space, or it can be blank.

I wish to match the number in Col X with any of the number in Col Y, like so:

```
| X  | Y    | FLAG
---------------
| 8  | 8 13 | Yes <-- 8 is a match
| 1  | 8 13 | No <-- Even though 1 appears in Col Y, it is technically number 13 
| 5  | 8 13 | No
| 13 | 8 13 | Yes
| 3  | 8 13 | No <-- Even though 3 appears in Col Y, it is technically number 13 
| 14 | 7    | No
| 14 |      | No
```

I tried to unlist the numbers like so:

```
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(data$colY, "[\\.0-9e-]+")
```

But this only separates the numbers. How can this be achieved?

Comment: `mapply(grepl, sprintf("\\b%s\\b", df$X), df$Y, USE.NAMES = FALSE)`

Comment: this returns TRUE or FALSE for each line. How can I get it to return Yes or No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `str_detect` which is `Vectorized` over the 'string' and 'pattern'.  Inorder to make sure no partial matches, `paste` word boundary (`\\b`) on the 'X' column

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(FLAG = c("No", "Yes")[1 + str_detect(Y, str_c("\\b", X, "\\b"))])
```

-output

```
#   X    Y FLAG
#1  8 8 13  Yes
#2  1 8 13   No
#3  5 8 13   No
#4 13 8 13  Yes
#5  3 8 13   No
#6 14    7   No
#7 14        No
```

---

In `base R`, we could use `read.table` to read as numeric columns and then with `rowSums` create a logical vector

```
c("No", "Yes")[1 + (rowSums(read.table(text = df1$Y, header = FALSE,
     fill = TRUE) == df1$X, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c(8, 1, 5, 13, 3, 14, 14), Y = c("8 13", "8 13", 
"8 13", "8 13", "8 13", "7", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: the first solution is good, but it returns Yes for blank values in col Y. How can this show as No instead?

Comment: @Michael I get `No` in the last row.  Can you test it on the data in my post.  Do you have blank as `""` or `NA`

Comment: I am using `df$Y[is.na(df$Y)] <- ""` to replace all of the NA values with a blank cell. Then when I use the solution above, it returns 'Yes' in all the blank rows. Should I amend the NA's in a different way to avoid this?

Comment: @Michael If it an `NA` element, it returns `NA` for me.  Can you show the `dput(df$Y)`

Comment: @Michael `dput` gives the structure so that I can reproduce and test your original data

Comment: Yes I get NA also if it is NA. Perhaps there is a way to just make NA in col Y to blank and Flag to No in these cases? I am unsure how to show `dput(df$Y)`, sorry.

Comment: @Michael I am not sure if this is related to any package version behavior or not.  If you are getting Yes for blank values.  you can assign them as `df$FLAG[df$Y ==''] <- "No"`

Comment: ok I am going to use that. Accepting this as the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`strsplit` then check if the value is in the corresponding `list`. Let's remake the data first:

```
dat <- data.frame(X=c(8L, 1L, 5L, 13L, 3L, 14L),
                  Y=c("8 13", "8 13", "8 13", "8 13", "8 13", "7"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then do the comparison:

```
mapply(`%in%`, dat$X, strsplit(dat$Y, "\\s+"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```